# Firebase - Android. Restar stock de un carro de compras

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy desarrollando una tienda de productos con carrito de compras y bla bla, lo típico. Sin embargo, tengo un drama bien raro jajaja. El drama tiene que ver con que, al comprar una cierta cantidad de productos, es obvio que se reste el la cantidad comprada al stock total del producto respectivo. Tengo un trozo de código que cumple esta función, pero al ejecutarlo, el stock total se va prácticamente " a la B " jajaja, dando valores negativos, y comienza a actualizar el stock infinitamente al negativo.

Cargo el carro de compras a través de un adapter, así se ve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora la base de datos es la siguiente:
Como pueden ver aún se esta actualizando el stock jajaja[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo importante, el código es este: 
Lo primero que hago es cargar todos los productos ingresados al carrito, en un ArrayList.

```
 //Se agregan a un ArrayList los elementos del carro de compras
    table_users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot productSnap = dataSnapshot.child("cartItems");
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> productsChild = productSnap.getChildren();

            for (DataSnapshot product : productsChild) {

                Product p = product.getValue(Product.class);
                products.add(p);
            }
        }
```

Luego, en el *OnClick* del botón comprar, agrego un *foreach* para obtener el id de cada producto ingresado y acceder al child respectivo, para luego setear el stock de producto.

```
  //Recorrer arrayList para comprobar que se ingresan los productos
                            for(final Product p1 : products)
                            {

                                table_prods.child(p1.getIdProd()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        Product oldProduct = new Product();
                                        oldProduct = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);

                                        int stockNuevo = 0;
                                        stockNuevo = Integer.parseInt(oldProduct.getStock()) - Integer.parseInt(p1.getStock());
                                        String stockNuevo2 = Integer.toString(stockNuevo);
                                        oldProduct.setStock(stockNuevo2);
                                        table_prods.child(p1.getIdProd()).setValue(oldProduct);



                                        products.clear();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });
```

Cabe destacar que en el *setStock()* para hacer una prueba, puse cualquier valor, por ejemplo "50" y todo ok, cambió todos los stock correspondientes a cada producto a 50. Debe ser un error de novato jajajaj, pero la verdad no tengo idea de que puede ser, por eso acudo a los expertos, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Tal vez sea porque estas limpiando tu lista en cada iteracion y no encuentre ningún valor. Salu2.